# How to use Google Apps Script to create an XML from the data collected in a Google Sheet?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I am attempting to use Google Apps Script to build a code that will take the data that is collected from a Google Form into a Google Sheet and convert it into an XML file. I have a main folder, for example we'll call it Jenn, and I'm looking for the code to automatically create a new folder within the folder Jenn to house the XML file where it pulls the name for the folder from the spreadsheet.

The issue I'm having is that the code I have put together is not creating an XML file nor is it creating a new folder to house it in. I'm at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is my current code:

```
function myFunction() {
  function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var response = e.values; // Get the form response values
  var companyName = response[3]; // Assuming Company Name is in cell D2
  
  // Get the "Jenn" folder in Google Drive
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Jenn").next();
  
  // Create a folder with the company name within the "Jenn" folder
  var folder = parentFolder.createFolder(companyName);
  
  // Generate XML content from form response
  function createXML() {
    var xmlContent = generateXML(response);
  }
  
  // Create and save XML file in the newly created folder
  var file = folder.createFile('FormResponse_' + new Date().toISOString() + '.xml', xmlContent, MimeType.XML);
}

function generateXML(response) {
  // Extract questions from cells D1 to P1
  var questions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("D1:P1").getValues()[0];
  
  // Generate XML content
  var xml = '<FormResponse>';
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    xml += '<' + questions[i] + '>' + response[i + 3] + '</' + questions[i] + '>'; // Assuming answers start from cell D2
  }
  xml += '</FormResponse>';
  
  return xml;
}

}
```

I have tried looking into already existing codes for this and also have asked ChatGPT but nothing I do allows for me to get the end result I'm looking for.

Comment: I would use Powershell which can query google apps and create xml.

Comment: I would not wrap two function declaration within another function declaration,

Comment: What is the point of returning something from a function that is driven from a google form submission?

Comment: Your `getActiveSheet()` will always return `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]`

Comment: I would create a JSON file but no matter what kind of a file you want you will still have to figure out what kind of a structure you wish it to have.  With JSON it's easy to bring it in to Google Apps Script or Javascript as an Ojbect.

Comment: I'm creating a Fillable PDF Form and am needing an XML file from the data in the spreadsheet to be able to import it into the form so it isn't something that has to be manually typed in. I haven't really done any coding in the past so all of this is new to me and from researching I learned that creating a code and putting it into Google Apps Script is the best option to accomplish this.

Comment: @Cooper Can you please elaborate on your comment: getActiveSheet() will always return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]. I had ChatGPT help me with creating this code.

Comment: Because when  a trigger runs  a function that opens up a document it never creates a user interface because the system knows that it came from a trigger and not a user.  With no ui then all calls too getActiveSheet() return the left most sheet.